# Fixed footer is cut off in Instagram in-app browser

Tags: wordpress, instagram, footer, inappbrowser

When accessing my site from the Instagram in-app browser, the footer is cut off as shown in the picture below.
[Screen with cut off footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6zu1.png)

When the app is minimized and reopened, the footer is displayed normally as shown below.
[Screen displayed normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBUJP.png)

I think the bottom navigation of the Instagram in-app browser covers the fixed footer.

The footer has position: fixed applied, and I want it to be fixed to the bottom of the viewport like the second picture.
Any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Same problem, did you find any solutions?

Comment: same problem here this is so annoying